# Execute OSX command within python

Tags: python

I have a python 3.x script that requires accurate time. I use the following, within OSX  10.13.6

```
sudo ntpdate -vu time.apple.com
```

How can I execute this within python? Or is there a python native way to make sure my machine is properly synched with a time server?

Comment: can you not just call the command using subprocess? https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html `subprocess.run(["sudo", "ntpdate", "-vu", "time.apple.com"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout`

Comment: you can also try `os.system("sudo ntpdate -vu time.apple.com")` if you don't need result in variable.

Comment: @furas or with subprocess `subprocess.run("sudo ntpdate -vu time.apple.com", shell=True)`

Comment: @Boris subprocess has many functions to do the same :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)